# maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison. I am getting this error but I have no idea why I am getting this error in python

Tags: python

The function is defined as follows

```py
def bubble_sort(l):
    count = 0
    if count == len(l)-1:
        print(l)
        return
    else:
        count += 1
        for j in range(0, len(l) - 1):
            if l[j] > l[j + 1]:
                l[j], l[j + 1] = l[j + 1], l[j]
        bubble_sort(l)
```

When running the below example an error occurs

```py
l = [5, 3, 8, 6, 7, 2]
bubble_sort(l)
```

Comment: Your function is recursive. I’m not sure I can see anyway that it can terminate.

Comment: Please post your query clearly mentioning where you're encountering an error and what is the expected behavior you want. (Or simply make your question a little clear to meet the Stack Overflow requirements.)

Comment: The length of `l` stays the same and `count` resets every recursive call (in it's own local scope though)

Comment: Use [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-bubble-sort/) reference. Problem, as mentioned in comments,  lie with non terminating [recursion](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_recursion.asp).

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is that you're using recursion, but your stop condition will never activate because you reset `count` everytime you call your function. The fact is that a function can call itself a certain number of times, but here it nevers stops and your program meets this limits, hence the error .So what you could do is pass the `count` variable as a parameter to your function, which would look like this

```
def bubble_sort(l,count =0):
    if count == len(l)-1:
        print(l)
        return
    else:
        count += 1
        for j in range(0, len(l) - 1):
            if l[j] > l[j + 1]:
                l[j], l[j + 1] = l[j + 1], l[j]
        bubble_sort(l,count)
    

l = [5, 3, 8, 6, 7, 2]
bubble_sort(l)
```

it outputs this

```
[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```